# Access lifecycleScope inside RecyclerViewAdapter

Tags: android, kotlin

I need to acess my room DB inside onBindViewHolder. It worsk great when using in Activity. But how I launch lifecycleScope inside onBindViewHolder?

```
import androidx.lifecycle.lifecycleScope

class ProjectRecyclerViewAdapter(

    private val values: ArrayList<ProjectEntity>,
    private val itemClickListener: OnProjectItemClickListener
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ProjectRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    lateinit var context: Context

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val view =
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.fragment_item_project, parent, false)
        context = parent.context
        return ViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {

        val item = values[position]
        holder.name.text  = item.title

        lifecycleScope.launch {
            DataBaseHelper.getRolesByIDFromDB(context, item.fsId!!)
        }


    }

}
```

Comment: Calling this inside `onBindViewHolder` is not a good idea .. lifecycleScopewill be available in UI component . you should build your data outside the adapter and once built then notify the adapter ..

Comment: why do you need to access the db in the adapter? It seems you want to show roles for the specific `fsId`, why not extract them together before you populate the RecyclerView?

Answer (score 2):

Well, as what the others said, it is not a best practice to access DB in `adapter`.

It is better to access DB right after you got the the `ArrayList` data.

But if you insist, you can use this code

```
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val item = values[position]
        holder.name.text  = item.title

        GlobalScope.launch {
            DataBaseHelper.getRolesByIDFromDB(context, item.fsId!!)
        }
    }
```